# Generate array into new array

Tags: javascript

Hi guys i got a complicated case for me

I have 4 array like this

```
[
  {
    "Id":1111111,
    "OptionName":"Color",
    "VariantName":"White"
  },
  {
    "Id":2222222,
    "optionName":"Size",
    "VariantName":"XL"
  },
  {
    "Id":3333333,
    "OptionName":"Color",
    "VariantName":"GREEN"
  },
  {
    "Id":4444444,
    "optionName":"Size",
    "VariantName":"L"
  }
]
```

So i want to merge the ID like

1 on 1, 1 on 2,2 on 1, 2 on 2

The result should be like this, but depend by variant name, so colours merge to size

```
[
  {
    "Id":1111111_2222222
    ...
  },
  {
    "Id":1111111_4444444,
    ...
  },
  {
    "Id":3333333_2222222,
    ...
  },
  {
    "Id":3333333_4444444,
    ...
  }
]
```

I already found how to group them by option Name, but how to merge it?

this is the code how i group them

```
    const filteredVariantCats = variantCats
      .map((a) => a.optionName)
      .filter(onlyUnique)
      .map((optionName) => {
        let array = []
        return variantCats
          .filter((a) => a.optionName === optionName)
          .map((a, idx) => {
            array.push(a)
            return a
          })
      })
```

UPDATE RESULT THAT I WANT TO RETURN IS THIS

```
{
    id: null,
    combinationStr: a.ID+"_"+b.ID,
    name: a.variantName+' ,'+ b.variantName,
    hex: '#000',
    stock: 0,
    price: 0,
    priceDiscountType: OPTION.DISCOUNT_TYPE.NONE,
    priceDiscount: 0,
    weight: 10,
    code: '',
    attributeCode: 'a',
    active: true,
    productId: product.id from state,
}
```

Comment: There are missing commas after `Id: 1111111` etc. There are field names in different cases `OptionName` vs `optionName`. You are asking for how to generate the output but you write `...` in your expected output. Please clarify and make sure the code you post is accurately reflecting your actual code.

Comment: So is the current element merged with the next element?
For example 1 and 2, 3 and 4, 5 and 6 like this
In addition, which element of `VariantName` takes precedence after merging
`OptionName` and `optionName` are different, is the capitalization wrong?
If yes, which element of `OptionName` takes precedence

Comment: I suggest you supplement the full expected output or answer the question in the comments, these actions will solve your problem faster

Comment: @ian already update the output

Answer (score 0):

Assume the syntax error and mis-matched cases are just error you make while writing the example and not actual mistakes in your actual code. If I understand correctly, you want to split the array into two groups, colors and sizes. Then generate all combinations between the two. Here is an example of how to do so. Since you mark `...` in your expected output, I don't know what you actually expect so can only provide the `Id` field.

```js
const arr = [
    {
        Id: 1111111,
        OptionName: "Color",
        VariantName: "White"
    },
    {
        Id: 2222222,
        OptionName: "Size",
        VariantName: "XL",
    },
    {
        Id: 3333333,
        OptionName: "Color",
        VariantName: "GREEN"
    },
    {
        Id: 4444444,
        OptionName: "Size",
        VariantName: "L",
    }
];

const colors = arr.filter(it => it.OptionName == "Color");
const sizes = arr.filter(it => it.OptionName == "Size");
let results = [];
for(let color of colors)
{
    for(let size of sizes)
    {
        results.push({Id: `${color.Id}_${size.Id}`});
    }
}

console.log(results);
```

Comment: but how is the optionName is unique ? like theres a product with a difference variant, so its name different optionName, like optionName : shape, variantName : triangle,

Comment: Please clarify your question, give accurate expected input and output. Describe the problem clearly.

Comment: Do you mean you have arbitrary number of `optionNames`? If so what is the expected output? Merging `color`, `size`, `shape` all together into one single item? Or merging two at a time to output 3 items? If you don't describe your design clearly, people can't help you.

Comment: the optionName is only 2, but its have much variantName value, so its it can 5 size, 2 color, or 1 size, 2 shape